# After installing Nuget on Unity, building the game gives an error

Tags: unity-game-engine, nuget

I downloaded and installed Nuget's UnityPackage from [here](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity/releases) in order to use [DynamicJson](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dynamicjson).

I've successfully installed DynamicJson, but when I try to build it, I get an error as shown in the image below.

[image]

The error message is

```
Cannot build player while editor is importing assets or compiling scripts.
```

My project looks like this.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this error?

My version of Unity is 2019.3.10f1 Personal.

Comment: try to change the target nuget folder to somewhere outside the unity project folder

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried that method now and it seems to give me the same error.

Comment: please also check if any script contains `using UnityEditor`